# Using different word2vec training data in spaCy

Tags: python, nlp, word2vec, spacy

So I'd like to use some of [this training data](https://code.google.com/archive/p/word2vec/) in spaCy when I use the `similarity()` method.

I'd also like to maybe use the pre-trained vectors also on this page.

But the spaCy docs seem lacking here, does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the docs for this still aren't linked on the site! We're reworking the docs. But, does this answer your question: https://spacy.io/tutorials/load-new-word-vectors

Comment: Mostly yes. Do you know if the google news vectors I linked are compatible?

Comment: Also, are there any resources on training data into vectors?

Comment: The Google news vectors you linked should work fine. I think you missed the link though!

The Gensim docs have advice about training word vectors, as does the user group for word2vec. We're recommending you consider pre-processing the text with the spaCy tools before learning the vector. See the 'sense2vec' blog post for details on why this is helpful.

Comment: There's a link in the link in my question :P But thanks, very helpful.

Comment: hi @syllogism_ that link is dead!